# I was given an used HTC desire, doesn't boot, how can I reinstall it?

Tags: htc-desire, installation, clockworkmod-recovery

I never tweaked an android phone.

I was told to turn it on by pushing both the power button and volume down button.

I'm not sure if it has been rooted, I can read "clockworkmod" when I go into recovery.

Here is the whole phone and the text displayed. The third image is what I get when I go into the "recovery" menu.

[image: Screen] [image: Recovery] [image: CWM]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm just looking to make the phone usable again, what are my options ? If it involves reinstalling android, there is a 128MB micro sd in it, what should I copy onto it, or using some particular application ? I also have a micro usb cable.

Answer (score 1):

[clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) is a custom [recovery](/questions/tagged/recovery), so the device is probably [root](/questions/tagged/root)ed.

A 128 MB SDCard is as good as no SDCard at all, and probably cannot even hold a single image to flash. You might want to check for a bigger one, everything below 4 GB makes not much sense (make sure to buy nothing below class-4, class-6 is better, class-10 not really necessary). After that, check on [CyanogenMod.COM for your device](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=%22HTC%22;type=%22phone%22;searchable=%22desire%22;), and follow instructions there.

Before doing so, however: Have you tried to boot the device normally (just using the <kbd>Power</kbd> button)? It might even boot up normally. If not, you can execute the *wipe data/factory reset* item in the last screenshot, followed by *reboot system now* and see if that helps. If not, see above :)

Comment: I have larger microSD cards around yes. Booting normally, it show the HTC logo for 30 seconds or more, and then displays "android" text logo, which blinks with a 5 seconds period. The device is quite hot though.

Comment: If that stays the same even following a factory-reset, a fresh install might be the only thing left. If that doesn't cure it either, it might as well be some hardware defect.

Comment: how do you make a fresh install ? HTC sync doesn't seem to detect it when I plug it in.

Comment: Have you followed the link to the CM site? I did no deep-check, but the wiki page for devices usually includes full descriptions on that. And no, it doesn't work via HTC Sync. Usually it works via ClockworkMod's *install zip from sdcard*, which you can see in your last screenshot. But take care for all pre-requisites, processing, and after-work instructions the wiki might give.

Comment: I downloaded a zip which is only 88MB...